# ReactJS Changing style of a selector

Tags: reactjs

For the following code used in jquery, how can i code them in a reactjs function ? Can anyone help?

```
$('.row_1').css('display','none');
```

Comment: [`ReactJS DOMElement.style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Comment: @Hareesh Is that worked ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.row_1).style.display = "none";
```

or

```
this.row_1.style.display = "none";
```

considering row_1 will be look like something:

```
<p ref={(ref) => { this.row_1 = ref; }}>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
```

[Wokring demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jsch28)

Answer (score 0):

In React way, UI should render based on state

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div
      className="row_1"
      style={{
        display: props.visible ? 'block' : 'none'
      }}
    />;
  }
}
```

and you can use this component like:

```
<Row visible={this.state.showRow} />
<Row visible={this.state.showRow} />
<Row visible={this.state.showRow} />
```